# Converting components tuned in Object Inspector to be created at runtime having customized properties kept

Tags: delphi

I'm moving some DB access components (and related db functionality) from a form to another unit (not a data module). The particular components are of types `TIBDatabase`, `TIBTransaction`, `TIBQuery`, `TDataSetProvider`, `TClientDataSet`, `TDataSource`, `TADOConnection`, `TADOTable`, `TADOQuery`.

As a consequence, those components will no longer be available in the Object Inspector at Design-time because they will be created at Runtime. After those components are created, some of their properties need to be set (in order to chain link them, set LoginPrompt to False, etc).

While doing this I encountered the dilemma "how do I know which properties I need to set after runtime creation, *apart from the properties that were previously set when the component was placed on the form at designtime*"? I can tell which properties were set at designtime because the Object Inspector in the Delphi XE2 IDE will display a property in **bold** if a designtime value has been explicitly set for that property.

My question is, ***how sure can I be*** that the default property values at designtime are also enforced when the same component is created at runtime? Surely it depends on the source code for that component, but maybe there is a uniform methodology or standard template that most component makers follow. I don't know, and I'm not going to research how components are made (because that is unreasonable), so I'm seeking answers from suitably experienced experts. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default property values are assigned in a component's constructor and overwritten during DFM streaming.  Only non-default values are stored in a DFM.  RTTI tells the Object Inspector and the DFM system what the default values are. Thus you are guaranteed that default values are always the same regardless of how a component gets created, and regardless of whether a DFM is present or not.

You can look at your existing DFM for an idea of which properties change at design-time, but just because any given property does change does not necessarily mean it needs to be explicitly set.  Sometimes one property gets updated when another property changes, so you don't need to set both.

In short, in your new runtime code, set only the properties you know you actually need, and leave the rest to their defaults.

Comment: If - if - the component is written correctly, then properties that "gets updated when another property changes" would not be saved into DFM.

Comment: RTTI and DFMs have no concept of linked properties.  If a property setter changes the value of another property to a non-default value then that second property gets saved in the DFM. The only solutions to that for a component author are to either not link property values together, or else disable their native streaming and implement custom streaming.

Comment: *If a property setter changes the value of another property to a non-default value then that second property gets saved in the DFM* only when a component written poorly. In properly written component it would not. *The only solutions to that* - no. Read syntax of property declaration. Author should explicitly tell to RTL whether the property should be saved or not. Default value is just a reduced case of it. But you are not limited to it, you can use full-featured method.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the ways (choose any, or any another method)

1. Install GExperts for Delphi. Select your componments. Run "Convert components to code" wizard.
2. Install CnWizards for Delphi. Select your componments. Run "Convert components to code" wizard.
3. Right-click on your Form, select "View as text" (usually that is Alt+F12), find your components and copy them. You would have all non-standard properties listed. With little editing (using IDE record macro and text replace features) you can convert them to code rather quickly.
4. Right-click on your Form and make sure it is set to save its DFM file as text rather than binary, then open the DFM file in notepad or another text editor, find your components and copy them. You would have all non-standard properties listed. With little editing (using IDE record macro and text replace features) you can convert them to code rather quickly.